# Restriction of proper morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of affine varieties and let $Z$ be a closed subvariety of $X$.

Is the restriction of $f$ to $Z$ onto its image still proper?

thanks

Comment: Yes. A closed embedding is proper, and a composition of two proper morphisms is proper.

Comment: @gbp: The projection $A^2 \to A^1$ is not proper.

Comment: @gbp Your morphism $f$ is not proper. (Indeed, a proper affine morphism is finite.)

Comment: The base change of a closed immersion is a closed immersion and any morphisme of affine varieties is separated (or we can see immediately that a closed immersion is always separated since any immersion of schemes is a monomorphism and hence it is necessary separated) so a closed embedding is proper and after composition by $f$ we obtain also a proper morphisme (since the composition of a proper morphism is also proper).

Comment: Let $X=\mathrm{Spec} B$, $Y= \mathrm{Spec} A$ and $f$ be a proper morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$, hence $f_{*}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module and so $B$ is finite over $A$. In the other direction, a quasi-finite proper morphism of scheme is always a finite morphism.